# python selenium what is the best way to handle button is active or not active check for Click open of side page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Here trying to do a simple logic however failed getting right thing to get this done. Program fails into Exception mode here.
Here as shown in the picture wanted to click the private chat button ,after click this will become blue as in second image,i wish to click only if the current button is not active ,if active not wanted to click.
[image]
[image]

I just would like to click this button only if the current mode of the button is not clicked already (Not Blue).Tried with some code and not working.

Any working code will be helpful.

Here is the code i tried,that gets into exception

```
    try:
        #Message Private "Chat Icon" Click
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[data-name=pm_chats]').click() #this is successful
        time.sleep(2)
        if "button-3SuA46Ww isTab-1dbyVeUX isActive-1D4aU96I isGrayed-3O5VgbN4 apply-common-tooltip common-tooltip-vertical" in element.get_attribute("class"):
            print("This is very successful")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("some error")
```

Note : when the button is clicked the corresponding class shows this data that i tried in if condition to check in the element.get_attribute("class") this fails

**without Button click Element:**

```
<div class="button-3SuA46Ww isTab-1dbyVeUX apply-common-tooltip common-tooltip-vertical" data-role="button" data-name="pm_chats">
```

**With Button clicked the Inspect Element shows the below:**

```
<div class="button-3SuA46Ww isTab-1dbyVeUX isActive-1D4aU96I isGrayed-3O5VgbN4 apply-common-tooltip common-tooltip-vertical" data-role="button" data-name="pm_chats">
```

How this can be achieved in code , Need code support .thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
try:
    #Message Private "Chat Icon" Click
    chat = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[data-name=pm_chats]')
 
    chat.click()#this is successful
    time.sleep(2)

    if chat.is_selected()):
        print("This is very successful")
except NoSuchElementException:
        print("some error")
```

Comment: this does not work it gives the same result as it was my issue earlier ,Anyother methods